# passport-ldapauth get nested groups

Tags: node.js, active-directory, ldap, passport.js

I am using passport-ldapauth with my NODEJS+ExpressJS application.
I am trying to get the list of all NESTED membersOF the authenticated user but couldnt figure out how to do it.

My User "X" has a membership of "ROL-B" and ROL-B has membership of other 10 groups.
Now after authentication when it returns me the authenticated user object, i only see ROL-B as members of the group.
Is there any way i can get the full list of nested groups that a user belongs?

Here is my configuration
`"adAuthConfig": {
    "url": "ldap://localhost:8076",
    "bindDn": "CN=svcAccount,OU=Services,OU=Accounts,DC=misd,DC=net",
    "bindCredentials": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "searchBase": "OU=Accounts,DC=misd,DC=net",
    "searchFilter": "(userPrincipalName={{username}})"
  },`

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried with `passport-ldapauth`, but this worked for me using `ldapauth-fork` directly:

```
const LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN = '1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941'
const config = { ... your config here ... }
config.groupSearchBase = config.searchBase
config.groupSearchFilter = `(&(objectclass=group)(member:${LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN}:={{dn}}))`

new LdapAuth(config)
// etc
```

This will add a `_groups` property to the `LdapAuth.authenticate` result. That includes all the nested groups.